# Finding the minimum value across columns by group and when a condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr, min

I am trying to find the minimum value across two columns for each person in my data. I only want to consider values in one column for the minimum calculation IF a condition (in another column) is met. For example, my data look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
age = c(4, 5, 7, 11, 4, 5, 20, 25, 26, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
A = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 2, 3, 0.1, 0.3, 2, 3), 
B = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4), 
C = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4))

df
#  id   age     A     B     C
#   1     4   0.2   0.1   0.1
#   1     5   0.3   0.1   0.1
#   1     7   0.5   0.1   0.1
#   1    11   0.8   0.1   0.1
#   2     4   0.2   0.3   0.2
#   2     5   0.3   0.3   0.2
#   2    20   1.0   0.3   0.2
#   2    25   2.0   0.3   0.2
#   2    26   3.0   0.3   0.2
#   3     6   0.1   0.4   0.4
#   3     7   0.3   0.4   0.4
#   3     8   2.0   0.4   0.4
#   3     9   3.0   0.4   0.4
```

I want to find the minimum value of columns A and B for each ID. Column B contains the same value repeated whereas column A contains different values. I only want to consider values in column A IF age <= 5. My desired output is in column C.

You'll notice that for person 1, the value in column B is lowest and is returned. For person 2, the value in column A when age = 4 is lowest and is returned. For person 3, the values for column A when age = 6 and age = 7 are lower than the value in column B, BUT because age > 5, I am not considering those values and therefore the value in column B is returned.

I am trying to find a solution with dplyr but am open to anything. I have tried doing this in several steps with group_by and mutate but cannot seem to get anything to work. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(C = min(A[age <= 5], B), .by = id)
```

**How it works**

Hopefully this is clear how it works when `age <= 5` returns `TRUE`. Consider `id` when it is `3`:

```
age <- c(6, 7, 8, 9)
A <- c(0.1, 0.3, 2.0, 3.0)
B <- c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4)

A[age <= 5]
numeric(0)
```

Alone, sub-setting `A` by this condition returns an empty set. When you `c`ombine it with `B` though you get:

```
c(A[age <= 5], B) # only B values
[1] 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4
```

Essentially, when there is an age less than 5, `A` and `B` values are compared, but when this condition is not met, only `B` values are passed to `min`.

**Output**

```
   id age   A   B   C
1   1   4 0.2 0.1 0.1
2   1   5 0.3 0.1 0.1
3   1   7 0.5 0.1 0.1
4   1  11 0.8 0.1 0.1
5   2   4 0.2 0.3 0.2
6   2   5 0.3 0.3 0.2
7   2  20 1.0 0.3 0.2
8   2  25 2.0 0.3 0.2
9   2  26 3.0 0.3 0.2
10  3   6 0.1 0.4 0.4
11  3   7 0.3 0.4 0.4
12  3   8 2.0 0.4 0.4
13  3   9 3.0 0.4 0.4
```

Comment: Note: `.by` was added to `mutate` in dplyr 1.1.0. If you are using an older version you will need to do `df |> group_by(id) |> mutate(...) |> ungroup()`

Comment: another trick about `min` that people forget is that you do not have to use `c`. ie `min(A[age<=5], B)` will definitely work

Comment: @Onyambu, good point! Will update based on your comment. Always get that mixed up with `mean`.

Comment: This is great!! Thank you so much - I had been stuck on this for so long :)

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be done in one (mutate) line, but I'm separating it for simplicity.

```
df |>
   group_by(id) |>
   mutate(
     A_min = { if(min(age) <= 5) min(A[age <= 5]) else NA },  # First figure out if there is a valid value of A to use.
     C = min(A_min, B, na.rm = TRUE),
     A_min = NULL                                 # remove the extra column
   )
```